# Table not fount exception (E0729) , while executing hive query from oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Script_SusRes.q

```
select * from ufo_session_details limit 5
```

Workflow_SusRes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="hive-wf">
    <start to="hive-node"/>
    <action name="hive-node">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
           <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
           <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>default</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <script>Script_SusRes.q</script>
           </hive>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Hive failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

SusRes.properties

```
oozieClientUrl=http://zltv5636.vci.att.com:11000/oozie
nameNode=hdfs://zltv5635.vci.att.com:8020
jobTracker=zltv5636.vci.att.com:50300
queueName=default
userName=wfe

oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath = ${nameNode}/tmp/nt283s
oozie.wf.application.path=/tmp/nt283s/workflow_SusRes.xml
```

Error Log

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [10001] Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
```

Oozie Launcher ends

stderr logs

```
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/jobcache/job_201510130626_0451/attempt_201510130626_0451_m_000000_0/work/hive-log4j.properties
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'ufo_session_details'
Intercepting System.exit(10001)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [10001]
```

syslog logs

```
2015-11-03 00:26:20,599 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2015-11-03 00:26:20,902 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: Creating symlink: /opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/distcache/8045442539840332845_326451332_1282624021/zltv5635.vci.att.com/tmp/nt283s/Script_SusRes.q <- /opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/jobcache/job_201510130626_0451/attempt_201510130626_0451_m_000000_0/work/Script_SusRes.q
2015-11-03 00:26:20,911 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: Creating symlink: /opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/distcache/3435440518513182209_187825668_1219418250/zltv5635.vci.att.com/tmp/nt283s/Script_SusRes.sql <- /opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/jobcache/job_201510130626_0451/attempt_201510130626_0451_m_000000_0/work/Script_SusRes.sql
2015-11-03 00:26:20,913 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: Creating symlink: /opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/distcache/-5883507949569818012_2054276612_1203833745/zltv5635.vci.att.com/tmp/nt283s/lib <- /opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/jobcache/job_201510130626_0451/attempt_201510130626_0451_m_000000_0/work/lib
2015-11-03 00:26:20,916 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: Creating symlink: /opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/distcache/6682880817470643170_1186359172_1225814386/zltv5635.vci.att.com/tmp/nt283s/workflow_SusRes.xml <- /opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/jobcache/job_201510130626_0451/attempt_201510130626_0451_m_000000_0/work/workflow_SusRes.xml
2015-11-03 00:26:21,441 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2015-11-03 00:26:21,448 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@698cdde3
2015-11-03 00:26:21,602 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://zltv5635.vci.att.com:8020/user/wfe/oozie-oozi/0000088-151013062722898-oozie-oozi-W/hive-node--hive/input/dummy.txt:0+5
2015-11-03 00:26:21,630 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
2015-11-03 00:26:21,635 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev cf4e7cbf8ed0f0622504d008101c2729dc0c9ff3]
2015-11-03 00:26:21,652 WARN org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
2015-11-03 00:26:21,652 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
2015-11-03 00:26:21,663 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 0
2015-11-03 00:26:22,654 INFO SessionState: 
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/opt/app/workload/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/wfe/jobcache/job_201510130626_0451/attempt_201510130626_0451_m_000000_0/work/hive-log4j.properties
2015-11-03 00:26:22,910 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: <PERFLOG method=Driver.run>
2015-11-03 00:26:22,911 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: <PERFLOG method=TimeToSubmit>
2015-11-03 00:26:22,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: <PERFLOG method=compile>
2015-11-03 00:26:22,998 INFO hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: select * from ufo_session_details limit 5

2015-11-03 00:26:23,618 INFO hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
2015-11-03 00:26:23,799 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Starting Semantic Analysis
2015-11-03 00:26:23,802 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Completed phase 1 of Semantic Analysis
2015-11-03 00:26:23,802 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer: Get metadata for source tables
2015-11-03 00:26:23,990 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2015-11-03 00:26:24,031 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
2015-11-03 00:26:24,328 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
2015-11-03 00:26:28,112 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2015-11-03 00:26:28,169 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
2015-11-03 00:26:30,767 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=ufo_session_details
2015-11-03 00:26:30,768 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=wfe  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=ufo_session_details  
2015-11-03 00:26:30,781 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
2015-11-03 00:26:30,782 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
2015-11-03 00:26:33,319 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: NoSuchObjectException(message:default.ufo_session_details table not found)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_table(HiveMetaStore.java:1380)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.get_table(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:836)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1083)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8680)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:902)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.runHive(HiveMain.java:261)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.run(HiveMain.java:238)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain.main(HiveMain.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Comment: Is your table ufo_session_details part of default database in hive. In most cases, it is advised to use two part identifier i.e. database.table_name

For example: select * from database.ufo_session_details;

Comment: Yes its under default database...

Comment: Make sure that `hive-site.xml` is available on all YARN nodes that Oozie may run the Action on, and is present in their default Hadoop CLASSPATH. Otherwise Hive will not know how to connect to the cluster Metastore and will not "see" any tables.

Comment: Or, upload a valid `hive-site.xml` to HDFS and force Hive action to use that XML with `<job-xml>blah/blah/my-hive-site.xml</job-xml>`

Comment: HI Samson, Thanks for the help. I tried this and my error is changed to

Answer (score -1):

1677 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver  - 
1679 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver  - 
1680 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver  - 
1771 [main] INFO  hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver  - Parsing command: select * from ufo_session_master limit 5
2512 [main] INFO  hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver  - Parse Completed
2683 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer  - Starting Semantic Analysis
2686 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer  - Completed phase 1 of Semantic Analysis
2686 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer  - Get metadata for source tables
2831 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://zltv5636.vci.att.com:9083
2952 [main] WARN  hive.metastore  - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
2952 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
3952 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://zltv5636.vci.att.com:9083
3959 [main] WARN  hive.metastore  - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
3960 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
4960 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://zltv5636.vci.att.com:9083
4967 [main] WARN  hive.metastore  - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
4967 [main] INFO  hive.metastore  - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
5978 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer  - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to fetch table ufo_session_master